# How to count the occurrences of a string starts with a specific substring from comma separated values in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python. I am working with a dataframe (360000 rows and 2 columns) that looks something like this:
business_id date

```
P01         2019-07-6 , 2018-06-05, 2019-07-06...
P02         2016-03-6 , 2019-04-10
P03         2019-01-02
```

The date column has dates separated by comma and dates from year 2010-2019. I am trying to count only the dates for each month that are in year 2019 for each business id. Specifically, I am looking for the output:

[image]

Can anyone please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows

1. first use `str.split` to separate the dates in each cell to a list,
2. then `explode` to flatten the lists
3. convert to datetime with `pd.to_datetime` and extract the month
4. finally use `pd.crosstab` to pivot/count the months and join.

Altogether:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.split('\s*,\s*').explode()).dt.to_period('M')

out = pd.crosstab(s.index,s )

# this gives the expected output
df.join(out)
```

Output (`out`):

```
date   2016-03  2018-06  2019-01  2019-04  2019-07
row_0                                             
0            0        1        0        0        2
1            1        0        0        1        0
2            0        0        1        0        0
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are not datetime objects yet, you may want to start by converting the column (series) to datetime:
 `pd.to_datetime()`
Note: the `format` parameter.

Then you can access the datetime attributes through `.dt`

i.e `df[df.COLUMN_NAME.dt.month == 5]`